# How to pass byte array as a parameter in Spring Rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to pass few parameters, which includes byte[] as one, to a Rest Service. In the Service method when I consume the parameter and construct a File out of it ...I see a corrupted file. 
Below is my code:

```
public class MultiParameters {
    @JsonProperty(value="strName")
    public String strName;
    @JsonProperty(value="in")
    public byte[] in;
    public String strName2;


    public String getStrName2() {
        return strName2;
    }

    public void setStrName2(String strName2) {
        this.strName2 = strName2;
    }

    public String getStrName() {
        return strName;
    }

    public void setStrName(String strName) {
        this.strName = strName;
    }

    public byte[] getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public void setIn(byte[] in) {
        this.in = in;
    }
```

RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/upload",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void upload(@RequestBody MultiParameters obj){           
    try {
        System.out.println("str name :  "+obj.getStrName());
        System.out.println("str name2 : "+obj.getStrName2());
        System.out.println("bytes lenghts : "+obj.getIn());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Test.txt"));
        fos.write(obj.getIn());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can any one let me know what is the error over here?

I am testing my service by passing input as RAW Data in the form of JSON using Post Man.

Thanks.

Comment: public void setIn(byte[] in)  Did you set the byte[] from this function ? & did u printed the size of obj.geIn before wrtiting?

Comment: Yes. And it is printing the Size properly.

Comment: try adding  fos.flush();

Comment: one strange thing what I observed was..byte array which I am passing as an input is "5049504913104950491310504950131049501310495013104950" . When the control comes to service byte array contains "[-25, 78, 61, -25, 78, 61, -41, 125, 116, -29, -34, 116, -29, -35, 119, -41, 78, 116, -29, -34, 116, -41, 125, 116, -29, -34, 116, -41, 125, 116, -29, -34, 116, -41, 125, 116, -29, -34, 116]"..Input I am passing is getting corrupted or getting converted to another format set I guess. Am I correct? Any help in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can encode your byte array into Base64 string, then decode it back to byte array after receiving in controller.

Comment: I did the same already..but no luck..this is what I had done:

Comment: @RequestMapping(value= "/byteUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public void getValues( @RequestParam(value="str1", required=true) String str1, @RequestParam(value="str2", required=true) String str2 )
 {
  byte [] bytes=Base64.decodeBase64(str1);
  System.out.println(str1);
  System.out.println(str2);
  try{
  
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Test.txt"));
   fos.write(bytes);
   fos.close();
   
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

By given code, I am guessing that you are trying to upload a file. If that is the case you can simply upload file and accept them in controller as mentioned in below example where we are accepting one customer object and one file object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Customer saveFile(@RequestPart("customer") @Valid Customer customer, @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile file) {
    return customerService.saveFile(customer, file);
}
```

Comment: Agree with you. But because of some limitation I am unable to use MultipartFile option. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you remember how you get to resolve this?